# how do IoC this?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container, mef

I am looking to see how Ioc/Di can simplify wiring the following classes I use often.

Consider a library that has an abstract notion of an Entity and an interface for a data access object:

```
public abstract class EntityWithTypedId<TId> : IEntityWithTypedId<TId>{...}

public interface IDao<T, TId> where T : IEntityWithTypedId<TId>
```

For the dao, I have one implementation for NHibernate as well as a fake dao I find useful for testing:

```
// has an NHib implementation
public class Dao<T, TId> : IDao<T, TId> where T : EntityWithTypedId<TId> {...}

public class DaoFakeBase<T> : IDao<T, int>, IDisposable where T : IEntityWithTypedId<int> {...}
```

I currently do the following to define an Entity and Dao type for a given project:

```
/// <summary>
/// <see cref="IEntityWithTypedId{IdT}"/> with an int for an id
/// </summary>
[Serializable]
public abstract class Entity : EntityWithTypedId<int>
{
}

public class Dao<T> : Dao<T, int> where T : Entity
{
    protected Dao(ISessionFactory sessionFactory) : base(sessionFactory) { }

}
```

Can I use a DI tool to define the Entity instead? Can someone show me a code sample of how to do it if so?

Can you also lay out how I might tell my test assembly to use DaoFakes and production to use NHib.Dao

I have been looking at Windsor, mostly because NHibernate contrib projects use it, but am also interested in MEF, AutoFac and Ninject, in that order. I realize that MEF is not an IoC container in the sense that Windsor is. From what I can see with Windsor I would use Installer classes, maybe an EntityInstaller and a DaoInstaller, although I might be missing a FActory type of object here too.

Cheers,
Berryl

## UPDATE @ KeithS

Are you saying to change something like:

```
 class MyViewModel(IDao<MyClass, int> dao) {...}
```

becomes something like

```
class MyViewModel(Func<IDao<MyClass, int>, obj> getDaoFunc) {
    _dao = getDaoFunc(this);
}
```

Comment: You don't list Prism/Unity so I won't add this as a formal answer...however it comes down to simply registering an interface with a concrete type. You could wrap your definition in #if debug if you so desire; IUnityContainer.RegisterType<IFileManager, FileManager>(); Thus at runtime all resolutions for IFileManager will resolve to the FileManager type.

Comment: @Aaron doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose of using interfaces?

Comment: @Brian No...that is the only line in the entire app that references the concrete type. Everywhere else references the interface with no knowledge of the implementation details. In each module (as called by Prism) there is an init method where this registration takes place...which is a one liner as seen above.

Comment: @Aaron thanks; I'm not familiar w/ Prism/Unity hence my question.

Comment: @Aaron - do you think you could show me some code to do this using my classes, including having IDao be different for testing? Cheers

Comment: @Berryl In your update; using IoC/DI your MyViewModel would look just as it does in the first half of your example...class MyViewModel(IDao<MyClass, int> dao) {...} then IDao would get injected via the constructor which will resolve the concrete type via the container due to a previous registration within the container at an earlier point in time.

Comment: @Aaron, yeah. The fuzzy part for me is resolving what the TId resolves to. I am assuming a Unity solution would be translatable into another container once the registration bits are worked out, and not adverse to marking that as the answer if you want to take a shot at it.

Comment: @Berryl Added answer which will hopefully help...

Comment: @Beryl - Yes, I like that much more. You can provide lazy initialization by putting that into a property accessor or otherwise calling it at the last possible second, while the object still doesn't need to know where that function comes from or what it does.

Comment: @Keith. I agree that Locator is an anti-pattern, and you obviously have more experience here than me; I will try your solution out but I am struggling a bit to see how resolving the type through a delegate is cleaner than resolving the type to your container and then injecting it in.

Comment: Resolving the type through a delegate is in fact a little "messier" than simply injecting an instance of the type into the constructor. You can do it either way. Instance-injection is simpler overall. Delegate-injection allows for lazy instantiation of an object you don't need immediately, or maybe even at all (if your object can do some common tasks without the dependency). Method-injection can decrease initial load times, at the expense of making up that time later when you really need it (but likely aren't instantiating a bunch of other stuff as well).

Comment: @Keith. I actually was imagining (since I don't know) that some containers would be smart enough to JIT the instance if you tell it to. The injection itself is so simple and just good OOP anyway but I am finding that getting comfortable with container technology is surprisingly frustrating.

Comment: Well, the container must produce a real instance when asked (unless you architect some container that returns `Lazy<>` refs). Since most existing IoCs predate that .NET 4 addition, the go-to method for lazy instantiation is a delegate to the container which will resolve and return the dependency when called. As for understanding IoC, yes, it took me a while to understand it too. When you go to an IoC pattern, you often end up registering everything in the container, and only making explicit Resolve() calls at the outermost level(s) of the call stack, which cause all the injection up front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example...

```
class MyViewModel(IDao<MyClass, int> dao) {...}
```

...`IDao` would get resolved at runtime based on a previous registration within your container. The syntax for a Prism/Unity implementation is below...

```
IUnityContainer.RegisterType<IDao..., DaoFakeBase...>();
```

The `RegisterType` takes place within IModule.Initialize() of a given module as defined in the `UnityBootstrapper` class.

```
protected override IModuleCatalog GetModuleCatalog()
{
    ModuleCatalog catalog = new ModuleCatalog();
    catalog.AddModule(typeof(project.Init));
    return catalog;
}
```

You can also register a given type based on a lifetime manager; to behave as a Singleton...

```
IUnityContainer.RegisterType<IShellController, ShellController>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

...where the `IShellController` resolved instance will remain the same returned instance throughout the lifetime of the `IUnityContainer`.

**UPDATE:**

Using your code the registration would look like this...

```
    public interface IDao<T, TId> where T : IEntityWithTypedId<TId>
    { }

    public class Dao<T, TId> : IDao<T, TId> where T : EntityWithTypedId<TId> 
    { }

    public class TId
    { }

    public abstract class EntityWithTypedId<TId> : IEntityWithTypedId<TId>
    { }

    public interface IEntityWithTypedId<TId>
    { }

    IUnityContainer.RegisterType<IEntityWithTypedId<TId>, EntityWithTypedId<TId>>();
    IUnityContainer.RegisterType<IDao<IEntityWithTypedId<TId>, TId>, Dao<IEntityWithTypedId<TId>, TId>>();

    IDao<IEntityWithTypedId<TId>, TId> dao = IUnityContainer.Resolve<IDao<IEntityWithTypedId<TId>, TId>>();
```

Comment: What about the TId in IEntityWithTypedId<TId>, Would you try and register that as well? Also, how would the generic types for IDao look?

Comment: @Berryl Added code based on your request...and yes I would register TId if its reach moves outside of a single class.

Comment: sorry to make you work so hard! TId is typically either an int, long, or GUID (ie, a struct), so not sure about the class definition for it. IUnityContainer.RegisterType<TId, int>? You are closest to answering my question as to how an IoC might be used. Thanks

Comment: @Berryl I would wrap it in an interface of some sorts; where maybe you expose IId.ID or something similar. IUnityContainer.RegisterType<IId, TId>

Answer (score 1):

I would not use IoC to register the relationship between DAOs and their types (which is basically what you'd be doing). This will lead to you using the IoC container as a "service locator", a known anti-pattern where you pass the IoC container into objects that will use it to get the DAO they need.

I think the best way to simplify this from a consumption perspective would be to define a strategy pattern, using a factory class or method:

```
public Dao<T, TId> GetDaoFor<T, TId>(T objectInstance) where T:EntityWithTypedId<TId>
{
    //Here, you could use a Dictionary, Linq with some reflection, etc.
}
```

This one method can be injected as a delegate into classes dependent upon DAOs. The difference is that classes that need a DAO are dependent on a method that can give it to them, which can be provided by the IoC container; they are NOT dependent on the container itself (which is the primary source of evil inherent in the "service locator" pattern). This reduces the number of things you'd have to change if you re-wrote how you got these DAOs.

**EDIT:** A bit off-topic, but I opened the door:

The service location pattern is generally to be avoided, because it results in code that relies on the service locator. For instance, the following is common in code where the IoC has been exposed at child levels:

```
private IDependency _dependency;
public IDependency MyDependency
{
   get {
         _dependency = _dependency ?? IoC.Resolve<IDependency>();
         return _dependency;
       }
}
```

While this seems like a nice pattern (dependencies are lazily initialized, consuming code doesn't need to know about dependencies of the child, and you always* get a reference), this code will ALWAYS require the IoC singleton to exist. You can change the IoC framework behind it, you can remove the third-party tool altogether and roll your own, but this class will always require something on which to statically call `Resolve<IDependency>()`.

You also don't ALWAYS get a reference; you get a reference only if you properly registered IDependency with IoC. This produces two more weaknesses; 1) you don't know what the class will need without opening it up, and 2) if/when the call fails, it will fail deep in the bowels of the dependent class' inner workings. If you develop a new class, and plug it into IoC, it may pass integration, and even work in production for a while, until you start getting weird "object reference set to null" errors in really weird places in code, which are, trust me, a nightmare to debug.

Lastly, unit-testing service-locator-pattern code is more difficult, for the simple reason that you must mock the service locator as well as the dependency provided by the service locator. You can leave the production service locator in use, and simply register mocked classes as the dependencies, but that's not a unit test; the test relies on, and thus to some extent tests, that the integration of the class and its service locator works as expected. That's an integration test.

By contrast, dependency injection patterns free you from any dependency on how dependencies are resolved. The only requirement (in constructor-injection) is that they be around when the class is created. This has several advantages:

- If not using an IoC framework, you have to know what the class will need to instantiate it.
- If using an IoC framework, you get a runtime error when attempting to instantiate the dependent class, not sometime later when the object actually gets resolved.
- When testing a dependent class, you can more easily mock the dependency, because the dependency does not have to be fed in via the service locator.
- You can in most IoC frameworks still lazily initialize dependencies by providing a factory method instead of the actual dependency to the constructor. The above pattern then calls that delegate, which could come from anywhere, instead of a static named method which is satisfied by one and only one construct in the entire codebase.

Comment: What is your concern with being dependent on the container interface? Is it the need to swap out container implementations? You could always abstract away the container interface with your own.

Comment: @KeithS. I *think* I like what you are saying, but haven't got my mind around in yet (you always see example where the container injects an IDao). Are you saying a consumer would change to look something like the edit at the end of my question?

Comment: @Aaron. Keith isn't looking for container independence as much as he is looking to avoid using the container as a service locater.

Comment: @KiethS. Wouldn't a service locator anti-pattern imply asking some singleton to resolve a type inside the class, and be solved just by injection that type instead?

Comment: @Berryl I'm trying to understand Keith's concern with using the container as a "service locator"...

Comment: @KeithS Are your complaints akin to this...http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx or something different? While the linked to post brings up good points; I still don't see it as strong enough to deviate from the pattern in its entirety.

Comment: Basically, the service locator pattern results in an object graph that is reliant on the service locator, WHATEVER that locator is. You can abstract it away to make it implementation-independent, you can inject the service locator, whatever; your code will be written such that you cannot NOT have a service locator. Dependency injection, OTOH, does NOT require IoC at all; IoC simply provides *automated* dependency injection. If your objects don't KNOW about the IoC container, you can remove it completely and resolve dependencies manually, and the code doesn't know different.

Comment: By the same token, service locator-dependent code is notoriously hard to unit-test, and is in fact a hallmark of poorly-tested code. A unit test of locator-patterned code must not only mock the actual service, but also the service locator itself (or at least you have to set up an instance of the production service locator with registrations to all the mocks). There is also a very high chance of broken tests due to the service locator not being properly registered with everything it needs. By contrast, a class with injected dependencies requires you to mock only the actual dependencies.

Comment: @KeithS Creating an instance of a framework provided container is trivial; production or otherwise. The need for implementing the varying services is a necessity but implementing an interface in any modern IDE is yet another trivial task, especially when only a subset of functionality is being tested. The testing caveats you are speaking of seem much more positioned towards an integration test not a unit test. Integration tests are by definition more difficult to manage then a unit test. Either way all valid points and the OP and others should be aware of both the negatives and positives.

Comment: @KeithS. So... is my revised view model consumer close to what you are saying to do?